# Replicate an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one EC2 p3.large instance where I have installed several libraries, I want to make an exact replica of this instance as a backup. I need that this clone includes all the installed libraries, in that sense, something similar to a what a docker container does.

I have tried just to clone the instance as shown here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/clone-server/

But this does not kept the installed libraries and files from the original instance to the new one.

Comment: "But this does not kept the installed libraries and files from the original instance to the new one." it absolutely should. It's telling you how to take an exact backup of the server and create a new server from that backup. Are you sure you followed those instructions exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AMI of the current instance and use it for back up anytime.
[Related docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html#creating-an-ami)